# Not able to display correct data using pivot table

Tags: sql-server

Table structure:

[image]

This is the data for which i want to use pivot table

[image]

i want to display the result as

Teacher Activity [2013-11-22] and so on  The date field will display the count of the attendance.

Below is the code which i am using, result is coming as 0 under every date, which is not correct:

```
     DECLARE @temp AS TABLE(dates datetime)

        ;with cte (datelist, maxdate) as
        (
            select DATEADD(dd,-3,GETDATE()), GETDATE()
            union all
            select dateadd(dd, 1, datelist), maxdate
            from cte
            where datelist < maxdate
        )
        INSERT INTO @temp
        SELECT c.datelist
        FROM cte c 


        DECLARE @listdate nvarchar(MAX)  


        SELECT @listdate = (select(STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(convert(CHAR(10), dates, 120))                        
            from @temp ORDER BY dates asc                       
            FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '')))    

        print @listdate


        exec('(SELECT * INTO ##temptable from
        (select distinct teachername as Teacher,activityname AS Activity,memberid as attendance,
                QUOTENAME(convert(CHAR(10), attendancedate, 120)) AS DATES from
          tbteachertimelog inner join tbteacher on
        teacherid = tbteacher.id
        inner join tbactivity on tbactivity.id = tbteachertimelog.activityid
        left join tbattendance on tbattendance.activityid = tbteachertimelog.activityid and 
        convert(CHAR(10), tbattendance.attendancedate, 120) = convert(CHAR(10), tbteachertimelog.date, 120)
        group by teachername,activityname,memberid,
        attendancedate
        ) p            
        PIVOT            
        (            
        count(attendance)            
        FOR DATES IN ('+@listdate+')) AS pvt            
        )            

        ')
alter table ##temptable add TotalStudents int,meetings int,total64 int



    update ##temptable set TotalStudents = 
    (SELECT SUM(memcount) FROM (select count(distinct memberid) as memcount from tbteachertimelog 
    inner join tbattendance on tbattendance.activityid = tbteachertimelog.activityid and 
    convert(CHAR(10), tbattendance.attendancedate, 120) = convert(CHAR(10), tbteachertimelog.date, 120)
    where --teacherid = ##temptable.teacherid and tbteachertimelog.activityid = ##temptable.activityid
    --and
     tbattendance.attendancedate >= dateadd(dd,-7,getdate()) and  tbattendance.attendancedate <= getdate()
    group by convert(CHAR(10), tbattendance.attendancedate, 120)) x)

    update ##temptable set meetings = 
    (select count(distinct convert(CHAR(10), tbattendance.attendancedate, 120)) as dayscount from tbteachertimelog 
    inner join tbattendance on tbattendance.activityid = tbteachertimelog.activityid and 
    convert(CHAR(10), tbattendance.attendancedate, 120) = convert(CHAR(10), tbteachertimelog.date, 120)
    where teacherid = ##temptable.teacherid and tbteachertimelog.activityid = ##temptable.activityid)


    select * from ##temptable  

    drop table ##temptable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the following line in your subquery:

```
QUOTENAME(convert(CHAR(10), attendancedate, 120)) AS DATES
```

The `QUOTENAME` is required when you are creating the list of dates as the column headers but since you added this to your subquery your dates in the table appear:

```
DATES
[2013-11-22]
[2013-11-23]
[2013-11-24]
```

But you want the dates being returned inside your subquery should be without the brackets:

```
DATES
2013-11-22
2013-11-23
2013-11-24
```

The PIVOT function is looking for dates that match your data but since you have the dates surrounded with square brackets you don't get any matches, as a result you are returning zeros for everything.

Your columns don't match your data because of the bracket -- for example:

```
Header     --                YourDate
2013-11-22 -- does not match [2013-11-22]
2013-11-23 -- does not match [2013-11-23]
2013-11-24 -- does not match [2013-11-24]
```

The query should be:

```
exec('
with data as 
(
  SELECT * 
  from
  (
    select distinct teachername as Teacher,
      activityname AS Activity,
      memberid as attendance,
      convert(CHAR(10), attendancedate, 120) AS DATES 
    from tbteachertimelog 
    inner join tbteacher 
      on teacherid = tbteacher.id
    inner join tbactivity 
      on tbactivity.id = tbteachertimelog.activityid
    inner join tbattendance 
     on tbattendance.activityid = tbactivity.id
  ) p            
  PIVOT            
  (            
    count(attendance)            
    FOR DATES IN ('+@listdate+')
  ) AS pvt            
)            
select * 
from data 
')
```